# Which version of CockroachDB am I running?

Tags: cockroachdb

I tried running `cockroach --v` and got an unknown flag error. What’s the command to find out which version of Cockroach I’m running?

Answer (score 1):

`cockroach version` returns the version of CockroachDB available from the command line. However, it's important to note that you can upgrade the binary in your path, but the actual cockroach service running on the server can be older.

To upgrade the server, you'll need to restart cockroach (`cockroach quit` then `cockroach start` using the newer binary). If you’re doing this in production, you can take the nodes offline one by one without compromising your availability (assuming you’re running a load balanced cluster and aren’t treating a single node as the only target of your client).

Comment: does this mean that a crdb cluster can run multiple versions of the binary (old and the new version) at the same time? I asume you meant bring down and restart the nodes one by one so you are never missing more than 1 node at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

"cockroach version" will give you the executable version (I would say). If you need something from the database itself, you could run the following query:

```
select version();
```

It looks like this:

```
$> /bin/cockroach sql <connection strings> --database=postgres --execute "select version();"
                                          version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  CockroachDB CCL v21.1.6 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, built 2021/07/20 15:30:39, go1.15.11)
(1 row)

Time: 2ms

$>
```

This works in both CockroachDB and PostgreSQL.
I hope this helps... ^_^